# How to modify color conditioning cells in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

Is there a way to change over 1000 color condition cells? I need to modify the font color and style. I am pretty new to VBA but I'm sure it can be done faster than highlighting the entire sheet and modifying each rule one-by-one. I do know that I can do the manage rules but I have over 60,000 cells with an average of 5 cells conditioned to one cell. In other works:

Cells A:1 through D:1 are test scores. These scores need to be changed to green if the score is more than or equal to the minimum passing score.

If (A:1) >= passgrade then set color to green.

I know there is an easier way than setting it manually. For now I have to change the individual cells accordingly (some with duplicate upon duplicate upon duplicate (etc) rules...one set of cells took 20 minutes just to delete all the excess rules (lesson learned, just use the delete all conditions when that happens).

Is there a simple code that can reference the cells (objects?) in Excel to speed this condition up?

I'm using Excel 2007. Hope that makes things clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Jeffrey, you need to give us more details on exactly what you are trying to do :) And if possible a sample of the file. This will only ensure a speedy solution ;)

Comment: Again, you need to provide more detail, but once you have defined one autoformat condition correctly, you should be able to use the format painter to "copy" the conditional format rules to the other cells. Make sure that you use the right relative/absolute references in your autoformat formula's.

Comment: All the relative/absolutes are correct. I haven't thought about the format painter. I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you're looking for, but it sounds like you have more rules than necessary. If you go to Home -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules... it will bring up a list of all of your rules and the range on the sheet that the rules apply to. In many cases such as this, you can accomplish what you are trying to do by deleting duplicate rules that do the same thing but apply to different cells. Does this get you what you want?